# $V$ be a real vector space ; does every seminorm on it comes from the absolute value of some linear functional on $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $p:\mathbb V \to [0,\infty)$ be a seminorm (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Seminorm.html ) on it ; then is it true that there exist a linear transformation $T:V \to \mathbb R$ such that $p(x)=|T(x)| , \forall x \in V$ ? If not true in general , then is it true for any special kind of real vector spaces ? Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try $p(x,y,z) = |x| + |y|$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If $p(x) = |T(x)|$ for some linear functional $T \neq 0$ then $U = \{x \in V : p(x) = 0\}$ is a linear subspace of codimension $1$ in $V$ and it is instructive to prove the converse.

Comment: what is your point ?

Comment: hello , you there ? I don't understand your answer